# How to reproduce this graph?

Tags: r, dplyr

Here is my code ;

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

col_link <- "https://ourworldindata.org/famines#famines-by-world-region-since-1860"
col_page <- read_html(col_link)

col_table <- col_page %>% html_nodes("table#tablepress-73") %>% 
  html_table() %>% . [[1]]

new_data <- col_table %>%
  select(Year, Country, `Excess Mortality midpoint`)

new_data
```

I would like to arrange the years and countries in such a way that I can use them in a graph but I can't. My objective is to reproduce this graph :

[image: https://ourworldindata.org/uploads/2018/03/By-continent-and-decade-01-768x538.png]

My problem is that in the "year" column, some data last several years for a country. For example to show that the famine lasted from 1846 to 1852 in Ireland it says "1846-52" and this is a problem because I cannot use the data in this form for a graph.

```
Year      Country           `Excess Mortality midpoint`
   <chr>     <chr>             <chr>                      
 1 1846–52   Ireland           1,000,000                  
 2 1860-1    India             2,000,000                  
 3 1863-67   Cape Verde        30,000                     
 4 1866-7    India             961,043                    
 5 1868      Finland           100,000                    
 6 1868-70   India             1,500,000                  
 7 1870–1871 Persia (now Iran) 1,000,000                  
 8 1876–79   Brazil            750,000                    
 9 1876–79   India             7,176,346                  
10 1877–79   China             11,000,000                 
# ... with 67 more rows
```

Comment: Why can't you use multiyear data in the chart? Whether you want to do that and how seems like a design question rather than a coding question. On the example, they chose to combine data by decade, but that's a decision you make based on context. Questions on SO should be more specific than this—what tools are you using to make the chart? How do you need to arrange the data that's different from what you have now? How did you try plotting it that didn't work?

Comment: You are right, so how could I reproduce exactly the same graph above?

Comment: Our World in data has a github repository where you can get their datasets and the code used to produce them https://github.com/owid/ If I recall correctly, they use D3 for graphing rather than R. However a good starting point might be to `group_by` the decade for each country/region. Then use a stacked bar graph along with `geom_text` to add the total for each decade.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's more of a question of data than R programming, you could try matching the year periods to the decades. However if a year range spans several decades the data should be 'split up' in some way (e.g. do a simple proportional split) to accommodate that. If the chart you linked to is made with this data, some assumptions had to made to adjust the data, without knowing those assumptions you won't be able to reproduce the chart.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30884046)

Comment: the more you know